# Box containing all the controls has disappeared from my VB6 development environment

Tags: vb6

I'm using the VB6 development environment, and when I started it up this morning, the project displayed as usual, but the immediate box also appeared (even though the program was not running).

However, the box down the left-hand edge where one selects the controls to add to a form has also disappeared. Does anyone know what that box is officially called, so I can find it in the help text, or point me to the place to get it back again?

Edit: I restarted the VB6 environment again and now the properties panel at lower right has vanished.

Comment: View -> Toolbox for the controls palette

Comment: @Alex K. Thanks; that option doesn't appear on the View pulldown, but at least I know what to search for now.

Comment: If it's not appearing there, that also indicates that the menu state has been changed or could be corrupt. They're stored in the same BLOB as the window states.

Comment: Its there for me, right click the tool/menu bar, *customize* and *reset* them all

Comment: @Alex K; thank you. Order has now been restored.

Answer (score 6):

As Alex K said, View, Toolbox for the control window, Properties/F4 for the properties window, etc.
If they keep disappearing randomly, it could indicate a corrupt value or even worse, general memory/disk corruption.

The values themselves are stored as a large BLOB under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visual Basic\6.0\` in the `UI` and possibly the `DockSDI` values. You could try deleting these and see if it happens again.

Comment: thank you. I didn't find this necessary, as Alex K's second suggestion fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There should also be an icon in your toolbar for displaying the toolbox.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; there wasn't, but after trying Alex K's suggestion, it's back again.